# OAuth Password Grant Replacement

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am currently in the process of wrapping my head around OAuth2 and OIDC. I know what all the grant types are (namely the grant types "Authorization Code", "Client Credentials", "Device Token" and "Refresh Token"). However, these four grant types do not include an option to pass a username and password. I get that there is a password flow, but this grant type is forbidden according to the [Security Best Practices](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.4).

I also get the problems with the password flow, but I do not know how to replace it - after all, the user needs to enter their credentials at some point.

Is there anything I am missing? I would have thought that there is a single, trusted client that uses the password flow and that all other clients are redirected to, when a user wants to sign in.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. I have an API where I need to allow a client to authenticate as a user but the users of the client have their own accounts on the client system and therefore can't interact with the user account that the client authenticates to the API with. The password flow is the only appropriate method. The credentials for the API are held in the client server and not exposed to the user so surely password flow is appropriate?

Comment: I think the deprecation of password grant doesn't take into account a scenario where the client needs to authenticate as a user with the API but the user logged into the client is different to the user that the clients logs in to the API as.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand this issue a little better now although I may be projecting my own requirements on to your question a little bit here.

The Password Grant flow previously allowed a single client to authenticate multiple **end** users with the API. Let's say you run a shop and your delivery company have an API. Your shop sets up a client and each of your staff members can log in to their own account via the client.
In this case to log in they need to provide the client ID and secret as well as their username and password which Password Grant allows.
However in order to pass the user credentials to the API, the client needs to handle them in plain-text.

That's where the Authorisation Code flow takes over. Essentially it defers the login process to the API and the user enters their credentials there.
But what if your client is the API user? The shop users log in to the shop application and the shop application authenticates with the delivery API as the shop not the **end** user.

The Client Credentials Grant is the appropriate choice here. The [documentation](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/client-credentials/) talks about using the Client Credentials Grant "outside of the context of a user" but this doesn't mean that the client itself can't be associated with user within the API identified and verified by the client ID and secret.
In this case the client has all the credentials is needs to handle logging in to the API without requiring intervention from the user.

In any situation where the API handles the authentication of an **end** user, it is fair to expect the user to be actively involved in the process and therefore to be able to interact with the login screen provided by the API via the Authentication Code flow.